# NetLogo- zombies: how to ask neighbors with specific patch-values

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to learn the basics of NetLogo.

I have created a breed called zombies. I can only control my zombies. 
Now I want my zombies to ask the neighbor-patch with the coordinates (0 0) to tell me the amount of zombies on the patch (0 0).
If the count is < 76, I want to move there.

What I have tried so far is:

`

```
    let counter 0
 ask neighbors [if patch-here = patch 0 0 [
                     set counter count [zombies-here]
                    ]
]
ifelse counter < 76[
facexy 0 0
fd 1
set moved 1
] [
ifelse [pxcor] of patch-here > 0 [
facexy 0 2] [
facexy 0 -2
]
fd 1
set moved 1

`
```

any help is really appreciated!

greetings

raf

Comment: 1. Don't put `zombies-here` in brackets.  2. Check for missing final bracket. 3. This code needs to be inside a proc.  (Try to post a [mwe](http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html).)

Comment: thank you very much! i am still having troubles when to use brackets, and in which position of the lines i need to put my commands.